# Facebook Comments Notification by Mail

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I was able to set up FB:Comments on my site and the comments posted are being show on the moderation tool. Is it possible that I get a similar notification by mail, when a user posts a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I have created this ultra lite weight WordPress Plugin called [Ultimate Facebook Comments Email Notify WordPress Plugin](http://www.decalsdesign.com/Ultimate-facebook-comments-notify.html). It will help you to get beautifully formatted email notifications when someone comments on your blog using already installed Facebook Social Comment Box …and also no settings are required for this plugin cheers :)

Comment: I have a mediawiki and a drupal site. What code can I add to create an email notifications when someone leaves a facebook comment?